# Arduino: Oled not working when SD library is included

Tags: arduino, sd-card

I'm currently trying to put together a datalogger with an OLED screen and am having issues when adding the SD library to the script. I've seen that others have gotten error messages when combining Oled and SD cards that is related to RAM. Though in my case, the code runs, there is no error message, but the screen doesn't display anything. The code below shows the "OLED code" where the Oled display wouldn't show anything when I added the "#include <SD.h>". Also, since I quite new to this, some constructive criticism of the code itself is also welcome

Thanks!

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include "Adafruit_MCP9808.h"
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>

Adafruit_BME280 bme; // use I2C interface
Adafruit_Sensor *bme_temp = bme.getTemperatureSensor();
Adafruit_Sensor *bme_pressure = bme.getPressureSensor();
Adafruit_Sensor *bme_humidity = bme.getHumiditySensor();

//oled definitions
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels

// Declaration for an SSD1306 display connected to I2C (SDA, SCL pins)
#define OLED_RESET     4 // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

// Create the MCP9808 temperature sensor object
Adafruit_MCP9808 tempsensor = Adafruit_MCP9808();



void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3D);  // Address 0x3D for 128x64
// Clear the buffer
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);


while (!Serial);
Serial.println("Loading");
 if (!tempsensor.begin(0x18)) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find MCP9808! Check your connections and verify the address is correct.");
    while (1);
  }
    
   Serial.println(F("Found MCP9808!"));
 tempsensor.setResolution(3); // sets the resolution mode of reading, the modes are defined in the table bellow:
  // Mode Resolution SampleTime
  //  0    0.5°C       30 ms
  //  1    0.25°C      65 ms
  //  2    0.125°C     130 ms
  //  3    0.0625°C    250 ms


if (!bme.begin()) {
    Serial.println(F("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor, check wiring!"));
    while (1) delay(10);
  }
  
  bme_temp->printSensorDetails();
  bme_pressure->printSensorDetails();
  bme_humidity->printSensorDetails();



}

void loop() {
  float temp = bme.readTemperature();    // get temperature in degree Celsius
  float humi = bme.readHumidity();       // get humidity in rH%
  float pres = bme.readPressure();       // get pressure in Pa

  tempsensor.wake();
  //Serial.println (tempsensor.getResolution());
  float c = tempsensor.readTempC();
  float f = tempsensor.readTempF();

  
  //float sensor=analogRead(A4);
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.print(F("Temp_1: "));
  display.print(c,2);display.println(" \tC ");
  display.println("");
  display.print(F("Temp_2: "));
  display.print(temp,2);display.println(" \tC ");
  display.println("");
  display.print(F("Humidity: "));
  display.print(humi,2);display.println(" %RH ");
  display.println("");
  display.print(F("Pressure: "));
  display.print(pres/100,2);display.println(" kPa ");

  
  display.display(); 
  delay(1000);
  display.clearDisplay();
```

Comment: Typically this is a symptom of overlapping pin assignments in the various libraries.  This in turn stems from 1) Not reading the datasheet for your parts and 2) blindly relying on libraries you don't understand and haven't code reviewed.

Comment: @TomServo okay. So one question regarding the latter (2), could you give me a hint for how one would go about "code-reviewing" an Arduino library and identify such problems? I'm suspecting that there is an issue with the "Adafruit_SSD1306.h" and "SD.h"? as these are the only ones who don't play nicely with each other. Others who have had this issue suggest that it's due to RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Its just memory problem. I fix it by decrease the resolution only for usage area.. Its not the best solution however good enough for me

Comment: Work for me too
```
//oled definitions
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 64 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 32 // OLED display height, in pixels
```

Answer (score 0):

This was apparently a memory issue.

I've now connected an Arduino Mega instead of a Nano, and the code ran nicely. I've also added the remaining piece of code that was necessary to log the sensor readings.

According to what I've read on other forums, the SD and SPI libraries take up quite a lot of memory.